# How should I store const strings such as validation messages?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, architecture, constants

Like any application, I use common strings for user feedback, validation messages, descriptions, button text and so on.

I'd like to store these strings in a logical place. What's the ideal method to do this? I don't think this is a matter of opinion; I suspect there is an answer.

I've looked at other answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304118/where-should-you-store-your-constant-strings-in-net), but I'm specifically interested in a comparison of the following three methods - i.e. a explanation of why one technique is better than the other two.

## Method 1 - Resource file

Resource files are used to store strings, but is this the best place for it? Aren't these used for localisation? Wouldn't a resource file get too big? If you use multiple resource files wouldn't it be hard to track down specific strings later?

[image: Resource file]

## Method 2 - Static class

A sort of global "Const" static class to store them all?

[image: Static class]

(A module is a C# static class)

## Method 3 - Littered throughout relevant classes

With this technique you have the relevant messages at the beginning of the class. The "UserAdded" string would go in the class that primarily uses that string.

[image: Relevant class const]

C# or VB.NET are acceptable in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 - easier for localization if you ever need to do that later. The main benefit of resource files is that you **don't need to recompile your code** to make a text change. Just change the file and upload it. Can they get "too big"? Of course, so can anything. If so, create multiple resource files.

Method 2 - easier to make a bunch of changes to strings, more difficult to find where each string is displayed in your app. You'll need to logically group your strings somehow.

Method 3 - easier to find where a string is if you need to change it, if you put the text into relevant classes. Downside is that if you need to change a bunch of strings you'll need to go through a whole bunch of classes.

If you need to change your strings often, or want to write an admin tool so someone else can change them, drive them from your database. That's my personal preference.

If you hardly ever need to change them, put them straight into your view. (ASPX, cshtml or XAML, whatever). After all, that's what it's for. How often are you going to change "User was added successfully"? Just stick it into your view where other programmers would probably first look for them.